# ALSA programming

Tags: alsa

snd_pcm_drain: Assertion `pcm' failed. What might be the problem? This happens when I call :

```
int Capture(){
    if(capture_handle)
        return -1;
    /* drop any output we might got and stop */
    snd_pcm_drain(capture_handle);
    /* prepare for use */
    snd_pcm_prepare(capture_handle);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: some code or #define in snd_pcm_drain ?

Comment: int snd_pcm_drain(snd_pcm_t *pcm)
{
 assert(pcm);
 if (CHECK_SANITY(! pcm->setup)) {
  SNDMSG("PCM not set up");
  return -EIO;
 }
 return pcm->fast_ops->drain(pcm->fast_op_arg);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `capture_handle` is NULL.
You cannot drain a device that does not exist.

Comment: mhh am not sure about that because am trying to do the real time audio..and I have configured the handle

Comment: If you don't believe me, put a `printf("capture_handle: %p\n", capture_handle);` just before the `snd_pcm_drain` call.

Comment: Any Idea on how I can set the handles? am using M-AUDIO Fast Track C400 external audio interface..thanks

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.